# Databricks sql, how to compare string escaping characters

Tags: escaping, databricks, databricks-sql

I'm analysing two columns to filter in records that don't look alike:

```
select firstname, name 
from tableA
where lower(firstname) != lower(name)
```

I accept names that match even if few special characters don't, for instance:

[image]

These two names to Databricks are deemed to be different (rightly so) but I want to escape that '-' charachter.
Is there a way to say 'look for different names without considering the '-' character'?
Or maybe a way to get a index on how much the two strings differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches for that:

- Do normalization of strings before comparison - lower or upper case the strings, replace all characters like `-`, multiple spaces, etc. with single space - you can use [regexp_replace function](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/regexp_replace.html) for that. Something like this:

```sql
select firstname, name 
from tableA
where 
  regex_replace(lower(firstname), '[- ]+', ' ') != 
    regex_replace(lower(name), '[- ]+', ' ')
```

It could be further simplified by creating a [user-defined SQL function](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-sql-function.html) for that normalization.

- if you want to see how "far" strings are from each other, you can use [levenstein function](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/levenshtein.html) that will calculate [Levenstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

```sql
select firstname, name 
from tableA
where levenstein(lower(firstname), lower(name)) != 0
```